# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException - But the email still sends

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012, mvcmailer

I have uploaded my WebAPI site to a staging server and when the application attempts to send an email via MvcMailer I receive an SmtpException, but the email does get sent, exactly as required to the correct recipient!

Very odd behaviour. Surely the email shouldn't send when a send exception is produced?

It is a new windows server 2012 build too and this is the first site, so it could be something else I've forgotten to do.

Anyone got any ideas what could be causing this behaviour?

Here are the config settings:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="no-reply@mysite.com">
    <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Here is the error:

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Failure
>   sending
>   mail.","exceptionType":"System.Net.Mail.SmtpException","stackTrace":" 
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\r\n   at
>   Mvc.Mailer.SmtpClientWrapper.Send(MailMessage mailMessage)\r\n   at
>   Mvc.Mailer.MvcMailMessage.Send(ISmtpClient smtpClient)\r\n   at
>   Rpm.ReportBuilder.Web.Controllers.EmailController.GetSendEmail(String
>   template, Int32 id)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__6(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","innerException":{"message":"An
>   error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection:
>   net_io_connectionclosed.","exceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","stackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader
>   caller, Boolean oneLine)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader
>   caller)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)\r\n   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message)"}}

Comment: does the mail get sent to more than 1 recipient (or cc bcc etc)?

Comment: nope, just one single recipient

Comment: bang goes my theory then

Comment: Your InnerException says this: `Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed`, so it looks like the e-mail was sent but before the server can return a success message the connection is closed and the client thinks something went wrong.

Comment: It works fine locally. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: There are some SO articles when you search for the net_io_connectionclosed error. It could be an SSL-issue that only applies to the 2012 server. Try sending mails with the standard .NET SmtpClient and see how that goes. (From what I've seen the MvcMailer uses the SmtpClient, too, but it may handle the connection in a way that is not supported by the 2012 server.)

Comment: The plot thickens. So a normal email with SmtpClient will send without an error. The MvcMailer must be doing something strange. I wonder what is not supported by the 2012 server?

Comment: Thanks for your help Florian - if I set the host IP in my config to the server IP, then it works. MvcMailer must be doing something odd.